# Return rows even if record does not exist when using left outer join

Tags: sql

I am trying to get Dates from `RepDailyInfo` table when the `RepDailyCollection.IsReceived = 0` and when the `RepDailyCollection` does have a record for that particular `RepDailyInfoID`. Is this possible in sql server 2005?

```
Select distinct RepDailyInfo.Date 
from RepDailyInfo 
left outer join RepDailyCollection c 
    on c.RepDailyInfoID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
where c.IsReceived = 0 
    or c.IsReceived = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditions into the `ON` clause of the join, because otherwise you need the join to find a row for the row to be referred to in the `WHERE` clause:

```
Select distinct RepDailyInfo.Date 
from RepDailyInfo 
left outer join RepDailyCollection c 
    on c.RepDailyInfoID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
    and (c.IsReceived = 0 or c.IsReceived is null)
```

Also note the use of brackets around the `or`, which are needed in SQL because "or" takes precedence over "and" and without brackets you end up with "(A and B) or C"

Comment: Thank you! I din't know that i can write 'and' condition in Outer join. Interesting to know. Thanks again!! :-)

Comment: No problem. Actually, this technique is very handy and it's something that hibernate can **not** do, which should be remembered if you ever try to write HQL queries of this nature - you have to use a native SQL query instead of an HWL one.

Comment: @ram I believe that `c.IsReceived = null` should be `c.IsReceived is null`.

Comment: @Ram Yep - error corrected. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do

```
where IsNull(c.IsReceived,0) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to filter right side of join in join itself:

```
Select distinct RepDailyInfo.Date 
from RepDailyInfo 
left outer join RepDailyCollection c 
    on c.RepDailyInfoID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
   and (c.IsReceived = 0 
    or c.IsReceived is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause is filtering after the `OUTER JOIN`. If you don't want that behavior, move the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`, like this:

```
select distinct r.date
from RepDailyInfo r
left outer join RepDailyCollection c on c.RepDailyInfoID = r.RepDailyInfoID
    and isnull(c.IsReceived, 0) = 0
```